# javascript/jQuery: validating numbers when using .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Hi all,

I'm validating my form, just checking if in the fields where a number should be the user has entered an string.

In the form there is a field where the users can add more fields if needed. 
Then the form is sent to a js function where I gather the fields added like this:

```
 params ='';   
var myAray = []; 
    $(".myfieldThatNeedNumbers").each(function(){
        myAray.push($(this).val());
    })
    params += '&myfieldThatNeedNumbers='+myAray;
```

Later params will be sent to my php file thanks to .ajax()

How can I validate that the values in field "myfieldThatNeedNumbers" are numbers?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: This [previous answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/304588) (Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()) may be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can try

```
!isNaN(Number(value))
```

EDIT:
Do you mean -

```
$(".myfieldThatNeedNumbers").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(!isNaN(Number(val)){ /* invalid number detected */ }

    myAray.push($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: This is what I was trying but I cannot make it work with my code, inside the each function :(

Answer (score 1):

```
var params = $( '.myFieldsThatAreNumber' ).filter( function() {
    return $.isNumeric( this.value );
} );
```

Elegant answer of the day™.

`$.isNumeric` requires jQuery 1.7 ([source for the shim](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.isNumeric), probably based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/851498)).

Also, `$.ajax` expects an object for the `data` parameter, so you need the following:

```
var data = {
    'myFieldsThatAreNumbers': params
};

$.ajax( {
    data: data,
} );
```

Or just:

```
$.ajax( {
    data: {
        'myFieldsThatAreNumbers': params
    },
} );
```

And jQuery will take care of creating the string for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".myfieldThatNeedNumbers").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if($.isNumeric(value)) {
           myAray.push(value);   
        } else {
           alert('Not number')
        }
    });
```

Read more about **[`$.isNumeric()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d+$/.text(string)
```

for while numbers.

```
/^\d+\.?\d*$/.test(string)
```

for floating point. add `[+\-]?` at front if you need sign.

For dollars you could use

```
/^[+\-]?\d+(\.\d{2})?/.test(string)
```